# SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6a7017, pid=1753, tid=0x64fdcb40

Tags: java, crash, jvm, coredump

Hi and thanks for reading,

I have the following error while running my program and can't figure out what the solution would be. I also looked at all the topics with a similar error here, but could not resolve my issue.
Here is the full file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6a70717, pid=1753, tid=0x64fdcb40
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-3~14.04.1-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x4ca717]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before sta
rting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x655a5c00):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1834, stack(0x64f5c000,0x64f
dd000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000b

Registers:
EAX=0x0000196a, EBX=0xb70b1000, ECX=0x61cf0940, EDX=0x61cf0818
ESP=0x64fdab40, EBP=0x64fdaba8, ESI=0x0000000b, EDI=0xfffff7ff
EIP=0xb6a70717, EFLAGS=0x00010213, CR2=0x0000000b

Top of Stack: (sp=0x64fdab40)
0x64fdab40:   64fdab70 61c91990 0000007b 0000001b
0x64fdab50:   61cce7a0 00020170 64fdab70 fffff7ff
0x64fdab60:   0000000c 00000018 5de99ac4 00000800
```

Here is the link to the full file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ZczvxT6z2qdlllYlVRLThHSXc

And the device crashes once in a day or 2 days, and this files gets created. Also following is the device configuration if that helps.

Memory 3.9GiB
Processor Intel® Core™ i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 4 
Graphics Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAICOS
OS type 32-bit
Disk 100GB

Thanks.

Comment: You have received compiler crash (C2), please provide the complete crash logs, i would be able to suggest you the workaround.

Comment: You should update your Java version the latest (Java 8 Update 144), if the problem still occurs, you will need to report a bug to Oracle.

Comment: Hello @Fairoz Thanks for your response. Here is the full file, i hope it helps.    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ZczvxT6z2qdlllYlVRLThHSXc

Comment: Hello @MarkRotteveel earlier the device was running on java 7, after which i updated it to 8_111,but the problem remained. Is this problem specific to java version?And that updating it again will solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, it could also be a hardware problem. But you should always first update to the latest version, because maybe it was a bug, and maybe it has been fixed.

Comment: Use -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com.xhibitsignage.annotations.JsonObjectMaker::getJSONObject as a workaround

Comment: The **This question already has an answer here:** link has no accepted answer.